# Transition from {{view Ember.TextField}} to {{input type="text"}}

Tags: ember.js

I am upgrading from Ember 1.7 to Ember 1.8.0-beta.2 (incremental upgrade, I hope to reach the latest 1.8.0-beta.4 without much trouble).

Apparently, [Ember.TextField](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html) is [deprecated](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/5294):

> DEPRECATION: Resolved the view "Ember.TextField" on the global
>   context. Pass a view name to be looked up on the container instead,
>   such as {{view "select"}}.
>   http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations#toc_global-lookup-of-views-since-1-8

This is my original implementation:

```
{{view Ember.TextField classNames="form-control" valueBinding="properties§name" id="name-id" placeholderTranslation="generic.name" required="true"}}
```

So I have tried with (as I have done with other views):

```
{{view "textField" ...}}
```

No luck:

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: textField must be a subclass of
>   Ember.View, not

So, it seems it is now a [component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_input). So I try with:

```
{{input type="text" classNames="form-control" value=properties§name id="name-id" placeholderTranslation="generic.name" required="true"}}
```

And it seems to work, but I am worried that I am maybe doing something wrong, because neither `id` nor `classNames` nor `placeholderTranslation` are listed as [supported properties](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_use-as-text-field) for the `input` component.

So here my questions:

- am I right in doing this refactoring `{{view Ember.TextField}}` -> `{{input type="text"}}`?
- what about the properties not explicitly supported? They seem to work in my case. Is this a problem of outdated documentation, or ...
- is there a list of generic properties supported by all components? I can not find any.

Comment: I too have noticed that an id attribute on a component is automatically set to the id of the element of the component. I have had to use the attribute `_id` when I wanted to pass in an id to be set on an element inside of the component, not the id of the components wrapping element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your questions on ember here is my answer step by step:

- Yes you are doing right refactoring

  ```
  OLD- {{view Ember.TextField}}
  NEW- {{input type="text" value="" name="" class=""}}
  ```
- "Class" etc properties are anyways supported by html input so when you will add class, placeholder etc things those will be automatically supported as per my understanding
- Also all property which are mentioned in [Ember Doc](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_use-as-text-field) other than that whatever is supported in [html](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) will always work. You can read the Comment mentioned in ember [Ember source-code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls.js#L17)

  ```
  {{input type="text" value="111" name="mytest" class="icon" id="wow"}}

  AND I got

  <input id="wow" class="ember-view ember-text-field icon" type="text" 
  name="mytest" value="111">
  ```